# Como guardar el mismo ID que se genera al hacer push en una propiedad del objeto en firebase?

Tags: firebase

Actualmente tengo un nodo llamado 'comunicados', el cual contiene el siguiente objeto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que la misma llave que se genero mediante push de firebase en ese objeto es decir "L_E401l0yZ...." se guarde en una propiedad de ese objeto, de tal forma que quede asi:

```
-L_E401I0yZmGMn12L07{
   fecha_creacion: "2019-3-5"
   mensaje: "mensaje del primer comunicado"
   titulo: "primer comunicado"
   id: "L_E401I0yZmGMn12L07"
}
```

Lo he realizado de la siguiente forma, pero no he tenido resultados:

```
crearComunicado(comunicado){
        let vm = this;
        let fecha_actual = new Date()
        let anio = fecha_actual.getFullYear();
        let mes  = fecha_actual.getMonth()+ 1;
        let dia  = fecha_actual.getDate();
        let hoy = anio + "-"+mes+"-"+dia;

        var myRef = firebase.database().ref().push();
        var key = myRef.key();

      console.log("KEY");
      console.log(key);
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref('comunicados')
          .push({
            titulo: comunicado.titulo,
            mensaje: comunicado.mensaje,
            fecha_creacion: hoy,
            id: key
          })
          .then(()=>{
            console.log("Comunicado creado exitosamente");
            vm.dialogCrear = false;
          })
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donde retorna la promesa podes mandar el objeto con el valor de tu key

```
   .then((snapshot)=>{
                myRef.child(snapshot.key).update({"id": snapshot.key})
                console.log("Comunicado creado exitosamente.");
                vm.dialogCrear = false;
              })
```